# Changing Entity Framework consumed classes after the DB has been created and deployed

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

Assume we have an ASP.NET MVC3 Web site that makes use of Entity Framework Code First approach to working with database.

The system is now working in test environment.

If the part of the DbContext is the following:

```
public DbSet<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
```

will it cause DB-Code collaboration problems, if I, for example, add Properties to an Incident class?

Or will the framework just update the Database tables automatically, and will treat the older records, that were created without new properties as if they are null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depand on your database initialization setting. 
(CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges, DropCreateDatabaseAlways)

eg: Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists())

- If you didn't set any database initialization, EF will use default
  initlizer "**CreateDatabaseIfNotExists**" and it would throw
  InvalidOperationError.
- If you set as "**DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges**", EF will recreate
  the Database based on your new Model. But you will also need necessary
  access right to create the database and it is dangerous if you are in 
  production environment.
- If you set as "**DropCreateDatabaseAlways**", EF will recreate the Database whenever
  you run the application.

Comment: With "DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges" option used at initialiser, will the actual data be repopulated, or will the contents of the prev. tables be lost?

Comment: The contents of prev. tables be lost.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I need to implement some kind of an update algoritm.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it will not update the database automatically, you will have an error message telling you that the Context has been changed. There for, you have to do a "Drop and Create" to the database !!